# albatross on Vanilla Tex Live does not run

Tags: texlive, linux, debian, java, texlive2022

I installed vanilla TeX Live on Debian instead of using `apt`. My `$PATH` includes `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux` so that I do not need to type the full path everytime I want to use `pdflatex` or other tools. I had no issues compiling .tex files but I came across one executable that fails to run.

`albatross`, the tool that helps find fonts that include a unicode character does not work. `which albatross` successfully locates the executable, returning `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/albatross` but when I run `albatross ¿` or `albatross 0xC4` or `albatross U+BD` they all exit with `Error: Unable to access jarfile`.

I ran a full installation so nothing should be missing and this is the only version of TeX Live on the computer. Am I missing some sort of Java dependency? How can I fix `albatross`?

Comment: what does `java -jar /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/scripts/albatross/albatross.jar` give?